# Transistor shortcut

Tags: transistors, 12v

i would like to fade an led strip using pwm with a n mosfet led that is commanded by a two way switch ( relay and sw1 ) like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwZGsv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sw2 is a rescue switch in case of command problem.

Can i shortcut my transistor using sw2 like this ?
Any better ideas ?

Comment: Yes, you can short a mosfet with a switch. But I hope you will pay some attention to polarity, right now the msofet is not connected the way it should be.

Comment: Why downvote ? Thank you for your answers the others.

Comment: If you want to bypass SW2 with a MOSFET, I would suggest using a P-channel device. To turn it on, drive the gate to GND. To turn it off, drive the gate up to 12V (or whatever V1 is at). Connect source to V1, and connect the drain to node in common between SW1 and SW2. If you use NMOS at SW2, you will have to drive it substantially above 12V to make it turn on.

Answer (score 1):

As in the first comment, shorting the pins of the Mosfet is OK.  Also as the comment the N-Mosfet is connected incorrectly.  To use an N-Mosfet for this function would require that it be connected on the low end of the circuit between the LEDs and the supply (with source pin at the "-" supply point).  A P-Mosfet could be used at the original position (with the input signal inverted).